# DevOps - Invalid configuration for solution file

Tags: azure-devops

Very new to VS/DevOps/pipelines, getting a failure for a given project:

> D:\a\1\s\Test.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "release|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

When I queue up the build, I set parameter `BuildPlatform = x86`.

The Test.sln file is defined as

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {02639838-9450-473C-915E-997E813F7FA4}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {02639838-9450-473C-915E-997E813F7FA4}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {02639838-9450-473C-915E-997E813F7FA4}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {02639838-9450-473C-915E-997E813F7FA4}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {1C672EE9-6178-414D-902E-8DCE45212052}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {1C672EE9-6178-414D-902E-8DCE45212052}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {1C672EE9-6178-414D-902E-8DCE45212052}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {1C672EE9-6178-414D-902E-8DCE45212052}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {C4A2147D-C432-484E-8994-85E91AF7AA74}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Do I need to edit the solution and explicitly add x86 in the Build Configuration section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `x86` configuration. You're telling it to build something that doesn't exist. Specify `Any CPU` instead.

Comment: I misunderstood what "Any CPU" means.  I understand it now.